# Help with Arrays for Java

Tags: java

```
// ****************************************************************
// Sales.java
//
// Reads in and stores sales for each of 5 salespeople.  Displays
// sales entered by salesperson id and total sales for all salespeople.
//
// ****************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    final int SALESPEOPLE = 5;
    int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
    int sum;
    int average;
    int max=sales[0];
    int min=sales[0];
    int salemade;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + (i+1) + ": ");
        sales[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    // Find maximum and minimum sale value   
    for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)

        if(sales[i]>max)
        max=sales[i];
        System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the max sale of $ " + max);  
        if(sales[i]<min)
        min=sales[i];
    System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the min sale of $ "+min);
// List of sales
    System.out.println("\nSalesperson   Sales");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    sum = 0;


    for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("     " + (i+1) + "         " + sales[i]);
        sum += sales[i];
        }

        average= sum/5;
    System.out.println("\nTotal sales: " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average sale is:$ "+average);

    //See who exeeded the max sale
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of sale made");
    salemade=scan.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i=sales.length; i++)
        {
        if(sales[i]>=salemade)
        System.out.println(sales[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to write this program that asked the user to put in the amount of sales of 5 people, and it will display the max and min value and print out the sale person id and amount of min and max sale("Salesperson 3 had the highest sale with $4500.") after the program prints the min, max and average, it will ask the user to enter a random number and compares it to those previous number and see who met or exeeded the max amount and print that person id. I'm having trouble getting it done.Can some one take a look and help me? These are the error i got

```
Sales.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable sale
location: class Sales
        System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the max sale of $ " + max);  
                                          ^
Sales.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable i
location: class Sales
        System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the max sale of $ " + max);  
                                               ^
Sales.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable i
location: class Sales
        if(sales[i]<min)
                 ^
Sales.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable i
location: class Sales
        min=sales[i];
                  ^
Sales.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable sale
location: class Sales
    System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the min sale of $ "+min);
                                      ^
Sales.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable i
location: class Sales
    System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the min sale of $ "+min);
                                           ^
Sales.java:57: incompatible types
found   : int
required: boolean
    for(int i=0; i=sales.length; i++)
                  ^
7 errors
```

Comment: You missed an s in the variable name . Its sales not sale. Other than that there is myriad of refactoring that you might have to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
...
System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the max sale of $ " + max);
```

You defined the array as `sales`, but then try to reference it as `sale`.

Comment: Oh right, but even when i corrected it, it still give me an error of Sales[i] not found

Comment: Make sure that you are writing `sales` and not `Sales`. Java cares about case.

Comment: I got it, one other question, how do I get it to print out the array index number, lets say I enter 10 for index 1, how do i get it to print "Sale person 1 has a max sell of $10" instead it prints "Salesperson 10has the max sale of $ 10"


This line of code isn't working for what I want to do
System.out.println("Salesperson "+sale[i]+ "has the max sale of $ " + max);

Comment: @Tuan: `System.out.println("Salesperson " + i + " has the max sale of $ " + max);`

Comment: @TuanNguyen: Based on that description, you just want to be printing the index `i` instead of `sales[i]`. Note that the index is 0-based, so for the user, they might expect the first salesperson to be number 1.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean, but my other question is if I have those printline within that for loop bracket, the program print out multiple lines instead of just the person with the min and the person with the max

Comment: @TuanNguyen: See @Aleadam's answer for comments about braces and only printing the message once.

Answer (score 1):

first, you forgot the braces in the line

```
for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
```

so you need to make it

```
int posMax = 0, posMin=0;
for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++) {
    if(sales[i]>max) {
        posMax = i;
        max=sales[i];
    }
    if(sales[i]<min) {
       posMin = i;
       min=sales[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Salesperson "+ posMax + " has the max sale of $ " + max);  
System.out.println("Salesperson "+ posMin + " has the min sale of $ "+min);
```

and here (line 57)

```
for(int i=0; i=sales.length; i++)
```

you need to **compare**, not **assign**

```
for(int i=0; i==sales.length; i++)
```

Comment: When I put the bracket for the for loop, instead of printing out just the min and the max, the output is 

{Salesperson 10has the max sale of $ 10
Salesperson 10has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 20has the max sale of $ 20
Salesperson 20has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 30has the max sale of $ 30
Salesperson 30has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 40has the max sale of $ 40
Salesperson 40has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 50has the max sale of $ 50
}

Comment: Yes, that what I was trying to do the whole time. Thanks!

Comment: @Tuan Good. Please consider also upvoting the answers that helped, since many replied with corrections :)

Comment: uh oh, problem...When printing the min value, Zero is always printed instead of the min, doesnt matter what values I enter, the max is right but the min always printed zero.

Comment: The problem is where you define `int min=sales[0];`. Move it after the first `for` loop. Right now you define it as zero, so it will never find any other minimum.

Comment: @TuanNguyen: `posMin` should be initialized to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Currently the answer has it is set to 0 and you don't have any numbers that that less than 0.

Comment: @unholysampler the problem is in `min`, not in `posMin` (posMin is never checked, but only assigned)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to fix your last `for` cycle to the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
    {
       if(sales[i]>=salemade)
       System.out.println(sales[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compilation errors are coming because you misspelled `Sales[]` with `Sale[]` in print statements.

Comment: Oh right, but even when i corrected it, it still give me an error of Sales[i] not found

Answer (score 0):

Line 33: There is no array named `sale`; your array is called `sales`.

Line 33, 34: The variable `i` is out of scope at this point. You should probably use brackets for the `if` statement and `for` loop. Java allows you to do an `if` without brackets, but it can confuse the compiler if the scope isn't clear.

When debugging compile problems, you should read the output and see which line numbers are causing problems. If the compiler can't find a symbol, it probably means your reference is out of scope or not there (for example, misspellings).

Answer (score 0):

try with code:

```
// ****************************************************************
// Sales.java
//
// Reads in and stores sales for each of 5 salespeople.  Displays
// sales entered by salesperson id and total sales for all salespeople.
//
// ****************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SALESPEOPLE = 5;
        int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
        int sum;
        int average;
        int max = sales[0];
        int min = sales[0];
        int salemade;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            sales[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        // Find maximum and minimum sale value
        for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            if (sales[i] > max)
                max = sales[i];
            System.out.println("Salesperson " + sales[i]
                    + "has the max sale of $ " + max);
            if (sales[i] < min)
                min = sales[i];

            System.out.println("Salesperson " + sales[i]
                    + "has the min sale of $ " + min);
        }
        // List of sales
        System.out.println("\nSalesperson   Sales");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("     " + (i + 1) + "         " + sales[i]);
            sum += sales[i];
        }

        average = sum / 5;
        System.out.println("\nTotal sales: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average sale is:$ " + average);

        // See who exeeded the max sale
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of sale made");
        salemade = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
            if (sales[i] >= salemade)
                System.out.println(sales[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but instead of printing out the person with the max sale and the person with min sale, this was the output 
{
Salesperson 10has the max sale of $ 10
Salesperson 10has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 20has the max sale of $ 20
Salesperson 20has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 30has the max sale of $ 30
Salesperson 30has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 40has the max sale of $ 40
Salesperson 40has the min sale of $ 0
Salesperson 50has the max sale of $ 50}

Comment: Also how do it get it to print the array index, let say index 1=10 then it would print "Saleperson 1 sale $10) I couldn't get it to print the index number with this line System.out.println("Salesperson " + sales[i]
                    + "has the max sale of $ " + max);